# Direct backwards with PHP

Tags: php

How do you direct back with `<?php include("./php/content/index.php"); ?>`?

Asin, if you are already on the page:

> www.address.com/about/index.php

how do you link it to the file:

> www.address.com/php/menu.php

I know it works if you put `<?php include("www.address.com/php/content/index.php"); ?>` but I was told not to use that methods as it is very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can go down the folder structure with two dots:

```
include( "../php/content/index.php" );
```

You can also use the file's full path on the server so you can use the same line everywhere:

```
include( "/var/www/php/content/index.php" );
```

Using the URL with `include()` is bad practice because

- you're retrieving the page using HTTP, even though the file is on your own server
- the server will parse the PHP and pass only the HTML content, so you lose e.g. variables
- you have to have the file accessible from the Internet. Using a file system path you can have the file outside the webroot.

Answer (score 1):

*Following examples **start** from **about/index.php***

In a relative anchor:

```
<a href="../php/menu.php">Menu</a>
```

In an absolute anchor:

```
<a href="/php/menu.php">Menu</a>
```

Unless you mean server-side, you can use `header`:

```
Header("Location: http://address.com/php/menu.php");
```

Or an `include`:

```
Include("../php/menu.php");
```

A better way is to have a common library in your website root from which you can reference a base location for all files in your project. That is to say, if you had **/common.php** that you included on every page, you could then store:

```
define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then an include from any document is as always referenced absolutely:

```
include(SITE_ROOT . 'php/menu.php');
```